# How i can get access to my textField in FlowPane? JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, methods

I have ListView with TextField and ProgressBar.

I want to get text from TextField by pressing button delbtn, but i cant figure out how i can reach this textfield in flowpane, in onClick(), flowpane is adding to listView.

I tried to use ListView.getItems() method, so i have FlowPane that i need, but i dont know how to get textField from this FlowPane.

And i tried to get flowPane.getChildren().get(0), i can see my text in console output[Output screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TomW.png)

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    URL xmlUrl = getClass().getResource("fx.fxml");
    loader.setLocation(xmlUrl);
    Parent root = loader.load();
    ScrollPane scrollPane = (ScrollPane) root.lookup("#scrlpn");
    scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);
    scrollPane.setFitToHeight(true);
    ListView<FlowPane> listView = new ListView<>();
    scrollPane.setContent(listView);
    TextField fieldAdd = (TextField) root.lookup("#edit_PID");
    Button buttonAdd = (Button) root.lookup("#btnAdd");
    buttonAdd.setOnAction(actionEvent -> onClick(fieldAdd.getText().toString(), listView));
    Button btnDel = (Button) root.lookup("#delbtn");
    btnDel.setOnAction(actionEvent -> onDel(listView));
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.show();
}

private void onDel(ListView<FlowPane> listView) {
    FlowPane flowPane;
    for (int i = 0; i < listView.getItems().size(); i++) {
        flowPane = listView.getItems().get(i);
        System.out.println(flowPane.getChildren().get(0));
    }
}

public void onClick(String procID, ListView<FlowPane> listProgress) {
    ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();
    progressBar.setProgress(0);
    listProgress.getItems().add(new FlowPane(10, 10, new Text(procID), progressBar));
}
```

Comment: please work through a tutorial on how to use fxml - in short: it _injects_ the fields into the controller.

Comment: thanks, sorry about arrows

Comment: no problem, I was too quick :) good you solved that!

Comment: As suggested, use a controller class instead of navigating the scene graph with lookups, etc. Also, it doesn't make much sense to put a `ListView` inside a `ScrollPane`; a list view will manage its own scrolling.